# replace with regex then undo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rather unique problem where I'm trying to run some jquery logic to replace text temporarily on a page. Then run some logic (I take a screenshot for a tool I'm using). So far this works great, the problem is that due to legacy code I need to revert the changes the replace call did on the page.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?
For the curious, I currently have:

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9\\*]*@.*\\.com/g,'[replaced for screenshot]'))
```

Thanks!

Comment: IMPOSSIBRU! Unless you store the value before replacing it, for example in `$("body").data()`

Comment: @mishik fair enough, ill let you **jQuery programmers** get back to work :);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd question your motives and reasoning, but I'll provided an answer nonetheless:

```
var backup_body_html = $('body').html();
$('body').html(backup_body_html.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9\\*]*@.*\\.com/g,'[replaced for screenshot]'));
```

Afterwards:

```
$('body').html(backup_body_html);
```

(Unless you need to keep hold of event handlers etc, in which case cloning is needed)

Cloning method:

```
var body_children = $("body").clone(true,true).children();
//other stuff (i.e. replacements)
//then:
$("body").html("");
$("body").append(body_children);
```

Comment: Questioning the reasoning is totally valid. Only considering this approach due to preserve a very large amount of legacy code. I'm not sure if the event handlers will be a problem (this worked fine in my smoke test). How would I go about cloning the page to preserve states?

Comment: @Valchris Sorry for the delay, see updated answer for the cloning method

Answer (score 1):

Not completely serious but I have to...

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: This is great, I'm tempted to say it's the easiest solution but I have a minor hiccup. I arrived to the page via POST, so I'm getting the "do you want to resend information you've already submitted" dialog box popup. Can I surpress that?

Comment: If it's ok to lose the POST vars you can do `window.location = window.location.href;`. If it's not ok, you'd have to do something like store the original POST vars within the page and submit a new form via POST.

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
var bodyHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
$('body').html(bodyHTML.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9\\*]*@.*\\.com/g,'[replaced for screenshot]'));
```

After

```
$('body').html(bodyHTML)
```

Comment: Seems like an exact duplicate of @SmokeyPHP's answer